# Read CSV into Apache Beam DataFrame with RuntimeValueProvider

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to create a template for a beam pipeline to run it on GCP Dataflow. The pipeline uses the apache beam dataframe module's read_csv to read the file. I want the file name to be passed in as an argument to the template.I figured out that the we have to use RuntimeValuePRovider for the same.

I have written the below code by using the documentation as a reference: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/creating-templates#using-valueprovider-in-your-pipeline-options

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.dataframe.io import read_csv
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions



class MyOptions(PipelineOptions):
    @classmethod
    def _add_argparse_args(cls, parser):
        parser.add_value_provider_argument('--file_name',
         type=str,
           default= 'gs://default-bucket/default-file.csv')


pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(
    runner='DataflowRunner',
    project='my-project',
    job_name='read-csv',
    temp_location='gs://dataflow-test-bucket/temp',
    region='us-central1')
p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)

my_options = pipeline_options.view_as(MyOptions)
# Hardcoding the file works fine: df = p | read_csv('gs://default-bucket/default-file.csv')
df = p | read_csv(my_options.file_name)
beam.dataframe.convert.to_pcollection(df) | beam.Map(print)
p.run().wait_until_finish()
```

When I run the code, I get the following error:

> Exception has occurred: WontImplementError 
> non-deferred 
> File "D:\WorkArea\dataflow_args_test_projects\read_csv.py", line 37, in 
> df = p | read_csv(my_options.file_name)

What is the correct way to access the RuntimeValueProvider when using read_csv?

Comment: You can pass the value in ValueProvider as mentioned in this [documentation](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/patterns/pipeline-options/) and then use [ParDo](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/transforms/python/elementwise/pardo/#example-3-pardo-with-dofn-methods) with Dofn. Let me know if that helps.